# Choosing selected files issue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Hi PowerShell experts,

I have a few files in a folder (folder A)with no extension (.file)

I have to change a few files content in folder A like this:

```
$configFiles=get-childitem . *. -rec

foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) | 
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'Cig - Prod Cen', 'Cig - Eco Gen'}| 
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

`Cig - Prod Cen` is replaced by `Cig - Eco - Gen`, but the issue is that if I do so, it will be replaced in all files.

How can I do the replacement for selected files?

Please can you help?

Comment: How do you determine which files are selected? You can specify those files in your script if there aren't many. Else you can specify a pattern in Get-ChildItem -Include [pattern] and only do those.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by filtering the file while reading them:

```
$configFiles= Get-ChildItem $FolderLocation -Recurse -Include *.config
```

now it will selected only the file type "config" and then you can do it as you suggested.

-OR-

this is what i did in my scripts, check before change:

```
if ($file.FullName.Substring($file.FullName.LastIndexOf('.')) -eq ".config")
```

now - it will proceed only for .config files and move on to all other (good for fixed list).

good luck :)

Comment: Yikes, the file objects have an extension property you can check. `$file.extension -eq '.config` should work.

Comment: that is much cleaner indeed :)
but i remember it sometimes have an odd behavior (can't remember why)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but I'm guessing you only want to perform the replacement on files that have no extension.
You can use the following Get-Childitem command to return files with no extension:

```
Get-ChildItem . | where-object {$_.name -eq $_.BaseName -and $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}
```

Comment: Hi Arluin, I have selected some files (with no extension) in a folder. Now i want to put a condition where it took the file with no extension + the file I have choosen.

Comment: Hi Arluin, i embeded it, it works fine after a few test on different files extension. I took 4 files, 2 with no extension, 1 xml and 1 html. i put the code above, it replaces only for the no extension. I also added a multi string where it search for a particular value before updating. this also works. thanks